# How to show that every point of this set is an isolated point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

If we define a non-empty set $S := \{ x \in [a,b] \ | \ f(x) = 0, f'(x) >0 \}$ , $f$ having a continuous first derivative, then every point of $S$ is an isolated point.

I truly don't know where to begin. I am assuming the key is in $f \equiv 0$ yet having a positive derivative. Is this a special case? Since $S$ is non-empty, I am assuming such set exists. So far I can only think of such functions that have this behavior at specific points, like trig. functions.

Comment: Kernel of $f$? Why $S$ is non-empty?

Comment: That is how it was defined. If it is non-empty, then it must have isolated points only.

Comment: *Hint*: Take $x \in S$. Then, being $f’$ continuous and $f’(x)>0$, there is a neighborhood of $x$ in which $f’$ is positive. Think about why $f$ can’t be $0$ in that neighborhood.

Comment: If what you are trying to prove is the first statement, I've posted an answer. If you are trying to find a function $f$ such that $S_{f,a,b}$ is non-empty, let $(a,b)=(-1,1)$ and $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in S$. By contradiction, assume it is not an isolated point. Then, for every natural $n>0$, $((x-1/n,x+1/n)\setminus \{x\})\cap S\neq \emptyset$. For all $n>0$
*choose* $\varphi(n)\in((x-1/n,x+1/n)\setminus \{x\})\cap S$. We then have that $\varphi(n)\to x$ so
$$f'(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(x)-f(\varphi(n))}{x-\varphi(n)}$$
But, since $\varphi(n)\in S$, we must have $f'(x)=0$, a contradiction $\rightarrow\leftarrow$.

We conclude that every element in $S$ ought be isolated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in S$ and $\varepsilon=f'(x).$ There exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$\forall h\in(-\delta,\delta)\quad\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h-f'(x)\right|<\varepsilon,$$
i.e.
$$\forall h\in(-\delta,\delta)\quad\left|\frac{f(x+h)}h-\varepsilon\right|<\varepsilon,$$
therefore
$$\forall h\in(-\delta,\delta)\quad f(x+h)\ne0,$$
which proves that $x$ is the only point of $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap S.$

Note that the continuity of $f'$ is useless.